# php filiter out special characters for userids and passwords

Tags: php, special-characters

I would like to prevent new users from including apostophes, quotations and other special characters in their userids and passwords as I've found these can create unexpected problems down the road.  Rather than anticipate every one of these problems, I'd rather just prohibit users from including those characters when signing up in the first place.

There are a lot of questions and stuff on the web in how to escape them to put them in the database but that is not the issue. I just want to throw an error msg that says enter something different.

I have tried:

```
$username = $_POST['username'];
if (preg_match ("/[&<>%\*\,\.\'\"]/i", $uid)) {
$strError="Your userid may not contain a special character.  Please try again.";
}
```

but this is throwing an error No ending delimiter `'''` found.

Would appreciate any suggestions.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are going about this the wrong way. Instead of blacklisting special chars try whitelisting letters and digits e.g.

```
$username = $_POST['username'];
if (!preg_match('/^[\w\d]$/', $uid)) {
    $strError="Your userid may not contain a special character.  Please try again.";
}
```

to include asterisk and semicolon:

```
$username = $_POST['username'];
if (!preg_match('/^[\w\d\*;]$/', $uid)) {
    $strError="Your userid may not contain a special character.  Please try again.";
}
```

Comment: how would I add non special characters such as a semicolon, asterisk etc?

Answer (score 1):

simplify it ...

```
<?php
  $username = $_POST["username"];
  if ( preg_match( "/^[A-Za-z0-9_]{3,20}$/", $username ) ) {
    // username is valid
  }
  else {
    // it contains special chars
  }
?>
```

explaining `regex`...

```
"/^[
A-Z # any uppercase letters
a-z # any lowercase letters
0-9 # any digits
_ # underscore
]{3,20} # minimum 3 and maximum 20 characters
$/x"
```

Answer (score 0):

The syntax highlighter shows you your obvious error: you have an extra `'` on this line:

```
$username = $_POSt['username']';
```

should be

```
$username = $_POST['username'];
```

Comment: that was a typo.  Already fixed.  The error is thrown by the preg-match line

Answer (score 0):

```
if (preg_match('/[^a-zA-Z]+/', $your_string, $matches))
{
  echo 'Your userid may not contain a special character.  Please try again.';
}
else
{
  // No special characters found
}
```

Comment: You should explain why your answer is correct and what the question-asker did wrong.

Answer (score 0):

may I suggest you not do that with preg_match ?

php has better functions for "sanitizing" strings - e.g. **filter_var** - check out [FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING](http://php.net/manual/en/filter.filters.sanitize.php)
I would suggest this snippet

```
$usernameRaw = trim($_POST['username']);
$username = filter_var( $usernameRaw , FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING, FILTER_FLAG_STRIP_HIGH);
```